# C++: How to properly link compiled object using CMake in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, linker, googletest

**OS**
Windows 10
CMake: 3.16.3
**Editor**
VSCode: 1.48.1
**Extensions**
CMake Tools: 1.4.1
C/C++ 0.30.0-insiders3
**Kit**
Visual Studio Community 2019 Release - amd64
<s>**Project Repo**</s>
<s>https://gitlab.com/NumeralRocket/kepler</s> *Removed, insufficient for minimal reproducible example*
**Tutorial**
Introduction to Google Test and CMake
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lp1ifh9TuFI

I'm attempting to build unit tests for one of my personal projects using CMake, and while I wholly admit I am quite new to CMake and a novice at C++, I am stumped on how to resolve this problem. When I go to build my project I get the following Linker error:

```
[main] Building folder: kepler 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build n:/Unreal_Engine/Magellan/kepler/build-vscode --config Debug --target ALL_BUILD -- /maxcpucount:14
[build] Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e for .NET Framework
[build] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[build] 
[build]   gmock.vcxproj -> N:\Unreal_Engine\Magellan\kepler\build-vscode\lib\Debug\gmockd.lib
[build]   gmock_main.vcxproj -> N:\Unreal_Engine\Magellan\kepler\build-vscode\lib\Debug\gmock_maind.lib
[build]   kepler.vcxproj -> N:\Unreal_Engine\Magellan\kepler\build-vscode\Debug\kepler.lib
[build]   gtest.vcxproj -> N:\Unreal_Engine\Magellan\kepler\build-vscode\lib\Debug\gtestd.lib
[build]   gtest_main.vcxproj -> N:\Unreal_Engine\Magellan\kepler\build-vscode\lib\Debug\gtest_maind.lib
[build] LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Quaternion.lib' [N:\Unreal_Engine\Magellan\kepler\build-vscode\test\QuaternionTests.vcxproj]
[cmakefileapi-parser] Code model version (2.1) of cmake-file-api is unexpected. Expecting (2.0). IntelliSense configuration may be incorrect.
[cmakefileapi-parser] Code model version (2.1) of cmake-file-api is unexpected. Expecting (2.0). IntelliSense configuration may be incorrect.
[build] Build finished with exit code 1
```

For context, the project is structured as follows:

```
${ProjectRoot}
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── Quaternion.cpp
├── Quaternion.hpp
├── googletest
└── test
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── QuaternionTest.cpp
```

**${ProjectRoot}/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16) # version can be different
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

set(This kepler)
get_filename_component(CODE_ROOT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} DIRECTORY)

project(${This}) #name of your project

project(${This} C CXX)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

enable_testing()

add_subdirectory(googletest)
add_subdirectory(test)

set(Headers
    Quaternion.hpp
)

set(Sources
    Quaternion.cpp
)

add_library(${This} STATIC ${Sources} ${Headers})
```

**${ProjectRoot}/Quaternion.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Quaternion.hpp"


// Default Constructor
Quaternion::Quaternion() {}

// Specified Value Constructor
Quaternion::Quaternion(double qs, double qi, double qj, double qk) : q0(qs), q1(qi), q2(qj), q3(qk) {}

Quaternion operator + (Quaternion const &quatA, Quaternion const &quatB) // 1) § 5.3
{
    Quaternion quatC;
    quatC.q0 = quatA.q0 + quatB.q0;
    quatC.q1 = quatA.q1 + quatB.q1;
    quatC.q2 = quatA.q2 + quatB.q2;
    quatC.q3 = quatA.q3 + quatB.q3;
    return quatC;
}

Quaternion operator - (Quaternion const &quatA, Quaternion const &quatB) // 1) § 5.3
{
    Quaternion quatC;
    quatC.q0 = quatA.q0 - quatB.q0;
    quatC.q1 = quatA.q1 - quatB.q1;
    quatC.q2 = quatA.q2 - quatB.q2;
    quatC.q3 = quatA.q3 - quatB.q3;
    return quatC;
}


void QuaternionLog(Quaternion quat2log)
{
    std::cout << "q0: " << quat2log.q0 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "q1: " << quat2log.q1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "q2: " << quat2log.q2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "q3: " << quat2log.q3 << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Quaternion quat1;
    Quaternion quat2(1, 2, 3, 4);
    Quaternion quat3 = quat1 + quat2;
    Quaternion quat4 = quat1 - quat2;

    QuaternionLog(quat1);
    QuaternionLog(quat2);
    QuaternionLog(quat3);
    QuaternionLog(quat4);
}
```

**${ProjectRoot}/Quaternion.hpp**

```
#ifndef QUATERNION_H
#define QUATERNION_H

class Quaternion 
{
public:

double q0{ 1.0 };
double q1{ 0.0 };
double q2{ 0.0 };
double q3{ 0.0 };

Quaternion();

Quaternion(double qs, double qi, double qj, double qk);

friend Quaternion operator + (Quaternion const &quatA, Quaternion const &quatB);

friend Quaternion operator - (Quaternion const &quatA, Quaternion const &quatB);

};

#endif /* QUATERNION_H */
```

**${ProjectRoot}/test/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

set(This QuaternionTests)

set(Sources
    QuaternionTest.cpp
)

add_executable(${This} ${Sources})

target_link_libraries(${This} PUBLIC
    gtest_main
    Quaternion
)

add_test(
    NAME ${This}
    COMMAND ${This}
)
```

**${ProjectRoot}/test/QuaternionTest.cpp**

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "../Quaternion.hpp"

TEST(Quaternion, QuaternionConstructors)
{
    Quaternion test_quat_1;
    ASSERT_EQ(test_quat_1.q0, 1);
    ASSERT_EQ(test_quat_1.q1, 0);
    ASSERT_EQ(test_quat_1.q2, 0);
    ASSERT_EQ(test_quat_1.q3, 0);
    ASSERT_EQ(1,1);
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
};
```

How can I:

1. Ensure and Inspect that objects are being built appropriately?
2. Properly instruct CMake such that the linker can find my Quaternion (source code) object?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: A [mre] needs to not depend on external links (some of which already return 404)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your last two links return 404 not found, for me... Your question post should contain all necessary code *as text*.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, I have replaced the link with the source code in individual code snippets

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was in adding my library incorrectly:
**${ProjectRoot}/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16) # version can be different
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

set(This kepler)
get_filename_component(CODE_ROOT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} DIRECTORY)

project(${This}) #name of your project

project(${This} C CXX)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

enable_testing()

add_subdirectory(googletest)
add_subdirectory(test)

set(Headers
    Quaternion.hpp
)

set(Sources
    Quaternion.cpp
)

add_library(${This} STATIC ${Sources} ${Headers})
```

I was adding a library named **${THIS}** which was "kepler" instead of the expected "Quaternion", so:

`add_library(Quaternion STATIC ${Sources} ${Headers})`

correctly tells the linker what/where to expect my library

**AND**

Leaving a main function in Quaternion.cpp, which was removed

Solution Source: [vector-of-bool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abuCXC3t6eQ&list=PLK6MXr8gasrGmIiSuVQXpfFuE1uPT615s&index=4)